# dynamic sidebar in front page

Tags: widgets, frontpage

I am developing TwentyTen child theme and wish to display dynamic sidebar on front page, but something is not quite right.

I modified `loop-page.php`:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('promotion-sidebar'); ?> //ADDED LINE
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyten' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyten' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

At first I was invoking it inside `is_front_page` conditional statement but then to double check issue I decided to call it on every page.
And guess what it appears on every single one except on the one I want: **THE FRONT PAGE**

***Edit: I am using Sidebar Template for my static front page.***

I just don't get it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: are you using a static front page?

Comment: yes Michael, I do.

Comment: there is no 'sidebar template' in Twenty Ten; did you create that yourself? does it contain some `get_template_part('loop','page')` code?

Comment: Man... I have such a nasty karma manifesting in my work sometimes. I wasted couple of hrs editing TwentyTen theme files but my Parent theme is actually TwentyEleven. And everything works just fine now upon editing that Sidebar template. Thanks for noticing this Michael, cannot express my gratitude enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loop-page.php` is the wrong context for what you are trying to do.

If you want it to appear on the home page, then you need to edit `loop.php`, so in your child theme you can either create a file called,

`loop.php`

...which should take precedence over the `loop.php` found in the parent TwentyTen theme or better yet create a file called,

`loop-index.php`

...which will take first priority over the above. By doing this and NOT creating a `loop.php` we will allow the `loop.php` file in the parent theme to act as a fall back in case something goes wrong.

Hopefully that makes sense.

In summary, you want to create a `loop-index.php` file (best option).

You can simply copy the contents of what you find in `loop-page.php` over to this `loop-index.php` file to give you the basic framework for your template, then you can modify the template to your liking.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried what you suggested, copying content of `loop-page` into newly created `loop-index` file with same structure as above, with no success. Even when I add simple line as `echo` some text nothing show up on front page. Is this weird??

Comment: I am using `Sidebar` template for my static front page.

Comment: Your sidebar template is taking priority over all else as you've set it as your static front page. Either you must edit that file or, unset the static front page option altogether and revert to using your custom `loop-index.php` for which you can style however you like.

Comment: Funny enough.. I cannot find the template inside twenty ten folder. I'll keep on looking. Thanks!

Comment: It might actually be a page you a referring to thats been creating in the dashboard area under Pages, not so much a template as in a [page template that you create](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) via `Template name: My tempplate` in the file itself. You may wish to double check that!

Comment: I was editing wrong theme folder all this time. Parent theme is actually TwentyEleven. Man oh man. But since your answer could potentially solve the problem and it made me learn new thing about Wordpress hierarchy I am accepting it!! Once again, thanks!!